# how to check BLE Gatt Client Mode is supported by device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In android, I have used BLE both mode as Peripheral and Client. But I want to check `isBLeGattClientSupported()`

As we know some devices in android are not capable to act as BLE Gatt Client so jut wants to throw an exception that such device is not able to act as client.

I have the rest of the past for BLE my code is working fine for both mode, but stuck when I said to my device to act as a client and that device is not capable to act as the client.

Answer (score 2):

This is straight from the [android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) -

> at run-time you can determine BLE availability by using PackageManager.hasSystemFeature():

The java example provided (a Kotlin example is also on the same page) to check the same is as follows -

```
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

This way you can check if your device supports BLE and throw an exception as required

Comment: This method will help us to check android device have BLE as a feature or not but in my case my device support BLE and can not act as a BLE Gatt Client. I just want to know the way to check the device is capable to act as BLE Gatt Client or not

Comment: @AmandeepTomar as far as I was aware, all devices with BLE functionality were able to act as clients. (Acting as a server is normally what is more intensive)

Answer (score 0):

All android devices that have a bluetooth chip (4.0 and above) running Android 4.3 above supports BLE and all these devices supports acting as a [BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt) client as well as a [BluetoothGattServer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer) as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Incorrect. There are devices that don't have a Bluetooth chip, and they therefore do not support the BLE features.

Comment: Right yes my bad, there could be devices that may not have a bluetooth chip, edited my answer.

Comment: Theoretically vendors could insert an old Bluetooth 3.0 chip in a phone with Android version >= 4.3, and then BLE would also not be supported...